# Field commentMapper in com.hs.news.service.CommentServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.hs.news.mapper.CommentMapper' that could not be found

Tags: java

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2unkJ.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWs5w.png)

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
ERROR 15176 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :
Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.hs.news.mapper.CommentMapper' in your configuration.